# In which order does sequelize.sync() create models?

Tags: sequelize.js

In which order does `sequelize.sync()` create models,
when we are trying to sync it first time?

```
sequelize.sync()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of operation for `sync` depends on foreign key restraints. It will create tables so that dependencies are visited before dependents. If you depend on a particular order of operations, you should manually sync yourself, e.g.:

```
User.sync()
Product.sync()
Animals.sync()
```

A few notes:

- The `sync` method calls the `modelManager` which [can be viewed here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/model-manager.js#L39-L81)
- You may already know this, but `sync` is useful for testing, but it should not be used in a production application (forced sync will drop tables if they exist, effectively deleting all data, this operation cannot be reversed). Instead, you should use migrations.
- There are known issues with the order of operations in `.sync({force: true})`, more in this ticket ([Sequelize drop table in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822663/sequelize-drop-table-in-wrong-order))

Answer (score 0):

The order of appearance of your models is concerned firstly, if foreign key restraints do not allow that order then sequelize will modify the order.